# Separate workspaces in Ubuntu 18.04 Desktop

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell, workspaces, ubuntu-dock, application-switcher

I have Ubuntu 18.04 on my laptop and I want to have completely separate workspaces on it.

Now my workspaces are sharing the icons on the dock, and when I click on icons of application that have instance in the the other workspace, it's taking me back to the workspace with the instance.
I want it to open new instance in the current work space, and I don't want any indication that the other workspace is running another instance of this application.

How can I achieve that?

**What solved my problem:**

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.app-switcher current-workspace-only true
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock isolate-workspaces true
```

Comment: And also:

gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock isolate-monitors true

Comment: https://varhowto.com/forum-topic/ubuntu-dock-how-to-show-windows-in-current-workspace-only/

Comment: Thanks for the solution. In my case (ubuntu 18.04 on a laptop dell), with option isolate-monitors to true, the ubuntu session seems unstable, all apps are closed when I switch to standby mode or if I close the lid.

Comment: It works for me on 22.04