# Is there a way to indicate if an app is open in the current or another workspace?

Tags: workspaces, dock

Is there a way to have the little orange dots at the side of the dock indicate whether the app is in the current workspace or another?
If for example two instances of Firefox were open in different workspaces at the same time, one dot should be orange and the other one gray.

Currently, I use a compromise by completely isolating the workspaces according to this description: [Separate workspaces in Ubuntu 18.04 Desktop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1068097/separate-workspaces-in-ubuntu-18-04-desktop) ; however, it isn't ideal either as it is the other extreme.

Any simple solutions?

The behavior I am looking for was actually the default mode in Ubuntu 16.04 (Unity). Instead of dots subtle triangles were used: [example-image-of-old-dock-behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Horuk.png)

Comment: The customization your asking for would prob require a programmer to configure that...No settings that I know of would.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Well, that's unfortunate, I really miss this feature. I also added a example picture of how it looked like previously.

Comment: If you have or create a github.com account, you can [submit a feature request](https://github.com/micheleg/dash-to-dock/issues) for the author of the "[Dash to Dock](https://micheleg.github.io/dash-to-dock/)" gnome shell extension, which is producing the Dock in stock Ubuntu installations. I don't see any way of tagging or categories there, but I see a few items in the issue queue that start with `[Request]` or `[Feature request]` in their title. Look up a few existing such requests to get an idea how one should be formatted, what it should contain.

Comment: Thank you for your helpful comments! I've now opened a feature request [here](https://github.com/micheleg/dash-to-dock/issues/1429).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, no. There is currently no option to allow having the marker for running windows have a different color if the window is not on the current workspace. The Ubuntu Dock is based on the Gnome Shell extension "Dash to Dock". Filing a feature request with the developers could cause them to consider adding this feature.